# Extending Help in Argparse to Subcommands

Tags: python, argparse

Consider the following code:

```
import argparse
p = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage="Here we go gathering nuts in May", prog="runfiles.py")
p.add_argument('-a', '--arg0')
s = p.add_subparsers(help="subcommand help", title="subcommands", description="valid subcommands")
sp = s.add_parser(name="subparser1")
sp.add_argument("--arg5", help="help me", metavar="BABYLON5")
sp.add_argument("--arg6", help="help", metavar="BEATLES")
p.parse_args(["--help"])
```

The output will be:

```
usage: Here we go gathering nuts in May

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -a ARG0, --arg0 ARG0

subcommands:
  valid subcommands

  {subparser1}          subcommand help
```

And if I specify the subcommand, the help message is:

```
usage: Here we go gathering nuts in May subparser1 [-h] [--arg5 BABYLON5] [--arg6 BEATLES]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
  --arg5 BABYLON5  help me
  --arg6 BEATLES   help
```

There seems no way to generate help for the `--arg5` and `--arg6` options, which are specific to the subcommand `{subparser1}`, at the global level, or for the global argument `--arg0` to be described at the subcommand level.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: That reflects how the parsers are organized.  If `p` sees the `--help` it reports on arguments it handles, including the subparser call.  But if it passes control to `subparsers1`, that parser handles the help display.  They don't "know" about each others flagged arguments.

Comment: I'm closing this because the **related** column found an old question that's close enough.  There may be others as well.